# If someone transfers money from a bank account to a prepaid master card, can he trace the master card back

Tags: credit-card, surveillance, money

Lets say someone traces money from his bank account to a prepaid master card. Then he doesnt get what he wanted, can he somehow cause problems, trace the card back anyhow or do anything?

Answer (score 2):

Not if you're a normal civilian, since we don't have access to bank transactions. If you're being tracked by the government (maybe under some process investigation), the government can request the bank your bank transactions, and maybe track down the origin of the pre-paid debit card to you.